# Access violation at glTranslate() call

Tags: c++, opengl, glew

I wanted to use glew with the Bullet physics engine and tried adding it to one of its demos.

I linked the glew lib to the demo and tried running it.

The program stops with an access violation error at `glTraslatef()` function call.

`glewInit()` works and loads other functions.

I noticed there is no `glewGetProcAddress()` initialization for this function.

What could be the problem?

The demo and this function worked before i added glew.

Comment: You're very-likely invoking undefined behavior somewhere. A debugger would be a logical next step.

Comment: There's not a single implementation that requires GLEW for `glTranslatef (...)`. That is an OpenGL 1.0 function. However, there are many implementations where that function no longer exists (it was removed in GL 3.1).

Comment: Im sorry if theres too little information here but i have no idea what to put out here. Do tell me in the comments.

Comment: Post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it was an access violation at the `glDrawArrays` call, not the `glTranslatef` call. And it occurred because of uninitialized buffers :(.